# Удаление данных в сетке DataGridView: нарушение параллелизма

Tags: c#, исключения, sql

Помогите, пожалуйста, пытаюсь удалить данные через DataGridView, выходит ошибка
Нарушение параллелизма: DeleteCommand затронула 0 из ожидаемых 1 записей. Вот код:

```
    OleDbConnection _connection = new OleDbConnection();
    StringBuilder ConnectionString = new StringBuilder("");
    ConnectionString.Append(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;");
    ConnectionString.Append(@"Extended Properties=Paradox 5.x;");
    ConnectionString.Append(@"Data Source=C:\Teplo\TepSeti\;");
    _connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString.ToString();

    try
    {
        _connection.Open();
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error openning database! ");
    }

    OleDbDataAdapter adapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Tepotp", _connection);
    adapter1.DeleteCommand = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM Tepotp");   
    adapter1.DeleteCommand.Connection = _connection; 
    adapter1.Update(dataset5.Tables[0]);

    _connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `OleDbCommandBuilder` для получения корректных команд. Ему нужно скормить адаптер, связанный с таблицей через `SelectCommand`, он прочитает её схему и сгенерирует команды для добавления обновления, удаления.